# schrodinger's cat experiment puzzle

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In Schrodinger experiment, the cat is both alive and dead until an observer opens the box to observe the radioactive decay - but why isn't the cat itself an observer?

Comment: Well, it is probably sleeping, so... (It is not a real experiment. It is a thought experiment. No actual cats were harmed while thinking about it.)

Comment: Hmmm - well if an observer is asleep.... or half awake I think that raises a whole lot of other ponderables, such as what counts as an observer

Comment: the silence is deafening - does a human observer count more than an animal observer- the thought experiment is lacking something, perhaps he didn't attribute animals with observational powers in which case what makes the human observer different?

Comment: The concept of an 'observer' in quantum mechanics is fuzzy at best, and more philosophical than anything else. Don't get hung up on it, focus on the physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max Born, a famous physicist of the pre-war years, said that the wave function doesn't describe a physical system but merely describes our knowledge of it. A number of other physicists at the time agreed with him, and there is reason to believe that Schrodinger himself agreed too. This resolves the paradox of Schrodinger's cat. Of course the cat is an observer and knows if it is alive, but the cat's awareness doesn't count, it is the awareness of the human observers that matters. The cat in the box is either alive or dead, not a superposition of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Because the cat itself is the point of observation, which is being observed by the observer. Its significance lies in that observation which is being done while keeping the point of observation free from the observation.